# How to read the value for a key from the info.plist in an config.xml file in my iPhone app

Tags: ios, cordova, plist

I am developing an Cordova app for both iOS and Android platforms. In iOS app, am loading the server url in the config.xml file with this `<content src="abc.xyz.com"/>`. But I want the get the server url from the info.plist dynamically.

```
<key>url</key>
    <string>http://abc.xyz.com</string>
```

So how can I read the value from info.plist into the config.xml file programmatically.

Thanks

Comment: ... explain what exactly you want to do. How should we help you with that less information?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I updated the code can u please check it now.?

Comment: You can't, config.xml is static and info.plist is static too, info.plist is a configuration file for the native part and config.xml is a configuration file for the cordova part. You can read both from code, but you can't modify none of them from code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"url"]
```

Comment: I need the same in xml file instead of the objective-c. I want to get the url value in config.xml file.

Comment: you will need to use an xml parser.
Here is a sample from Apple Documentation :
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I don't need to parse the xml file, I have config.xml file where I have to put the an url in the content tag for src attribute like this `<content src="abc.xyz.com"/>` and the abc.xyz.com is there in the info.plist file. 
My question is how can i get the url value from the info.plist into the config.xml?